# Redirecting after successful action

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I am currently working on a authentication project within React Native using the `react-navigation` package. So far so good, I have 3 Navigators setup, one for loading, one for auth and one for the application.

I have also got the navigation setup with redux so I can access it from any component via a prop, which is exactly what I wanted to do.

However, I have a question. I have done some research and can't seem to figure out the best way to do this.

I am dispatching an action from a press of a button `attemptLogin()` the attempt login then does what it says on the tin, it attempt to login.

After a successful login, I store the `access_token` in `SecureStore` using expo.

Now, upon the successful login I need to navigate away from the current stack onto the new one.

What would be the best way to do this, can you return a promise from a redux action? If so would the best way to be inside of the component and then inside of the component do something like

`this.props.login(username, password).then(() => { this.props.navigation... });`

Or would you do it inside of the action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recommended way as below:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(this.props.loggedInSuccessfully && !prevProps.loggedInSuccessfully) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate....
  }
}

onLoginButtonPress = () => {
  const { username, password } = this.state;
  this.props.login(username, password);
}
```

Upon successful logged in, update a state `loggedInSuccessfully` in your reducer and implement logic in `componentDidUpdate`. This way is the clearest for whoever gonna maintaining your code, in my humble opinion

Comment: That's brilliant thanks, I knew what I was trying to do I just didn't know the best way to go about it. I've implemented this and everything is working perfectly so thanks for that.

Comment: @tallent123: No problem! Just remember to mark it as answer to help future readers who stumbled upon the similar confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

you can also navigate from redux action or everywhere you want.

read the official [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html#docsNav) about navigation service.